# Tracing Designs - Screen to Database Traceability

Tags: database, user-interface, uml, modeling

This is vaguely related to:

[Should I design the application or model (database) first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329160/should-i-design-the-application-or-model-database-first)

[Design from the database first through to UI or t’other way round?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429905/design-from-the-database-first-through-to-ui-or-tother-way-round)

But my question is more about modeling and artifacts and less about the right way to do design.  I'm trying to figure out what sort of design artifact would best enunciate the link between features (use cases), screens and database elements (tables and columns, most particularly).  UML is very code-centric.  Database models are very database centric.  And of screen designs are UI centric!

Here's the deal... my team is working on the first release of the product.  We used use cases, then did screen designs and database design was somewhat isolated from the two.  A critical area for bugs was the lack of traceability between the use cases and their accompanying screens and the database.  In our product, there's a very high degree of overlap between use cases and database elements.  Many use cases touch over 75% of the database infrastructure.  So we have high contention over database design areas, and it's easy for a small database change to disrupt the lower levels of business logic.

For our next release, I want the developers and our DBA to have a really clear insight into what parts of the database each feature touches.  The use case/screen design approach worked well, so we're keeping it... the trick is linking each use case and screens to the database model so the relationships are really obvious and hard to forget about.

On smaller projects (we're only 10 people, but often I've worked on teams of 3 or less), I've created my own custom diagrams to show this part of the design.  Sort of a fusion of screen, UML and database table, done in Visio with no link to actual code or SQL.  I'm not sure it will work for a larger team, as its highly manual to keep up to date, and it doesn't auto generate code the way our database modeling tool does.

Any recommendations?  Is there a commonly accepted mechanism for this?

FYI - we're pretty waterfall, that isn't going to change any time soon.  And we do love artifacts...  Saying "switch to agile" is not a viable solution for our group.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell from your question how detailed your use cases are. I get the impression that they may be high-level use cases, not broken down into detailed uses cases (perhaps through *include* or *extend* relationships.

In any case, I prefer to start with Requirements, and trace them to use cases. While I'm writing the use cases and the use case diagrams, I'm also creating a domain model (a high-level class diagram). This is mostly to give me something to discuss with stakeholders ("did I get that right?").

When the use cases and domain model are finished, it's possible to begin to work on screen design, and possibly also for an activity model, if there are complex interactions between screens. I would treat the screens as though they were classes with UI - a screen might have a FirstName attribute, which I'd note as being related to the FirstName attribute of the Person entity in my domain model. Yet the FirstName attribute might be represented on that screen as a text box.

At the same time, physical database design can occur. This would produce a class or ER diagram, with traceability back to the domain model. Eventually, you might find that some of your screen attributes or activity modeling refer to things that are part of the physical database model that are not present in the domain model. It's ok to relate a screen "PersonalName" attribute to the computed PersonalName column in the Person table in the People schema.

The tool I use for this sort of thing is [Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/). It's a great tool, and can do all of this and more, even in the Professional edition.

I also have to say for the sake of Truth that I mostly model on my own - I haven't yet worked on a project where the model, code and database were being developed by separate people. If someone told me that the above wouldn't work in "real life", I might be forced to believe them.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question clearly, but I'll try to respond based on some reasonable assumptions...

Essentially, my recommendation is the same as what **John Saunders** already suggested: to consider using UML along with a good UML tool. But I would like to add a few points that might be important in your specific situation.

First and foremost, I don't think that UML is "too code-centric". To the contrary, it can be used to model pretty much any aspect of a software system, almost at any level of abstraction. With a good tool at hand (like Sparx EA), the beauty of UML is that you actually do get a well-defined model under the hood (as opposed to just a set of unconnected drawings/charts). As a result, even if the tool itself does not give you a feature that you are looking for (like traceability from DB to use cases)... well, at least you have an option to automate (or at least semi-automate) the task yourself: for example, you can export your UML model into an XMI (standard!) and then derive whatever traceability-related info you need from there (e.g. using XSL or any XML-aware library for your favorite programming/scripting language). I am not saying that it would be easy to do (especially if you want traceability on the level of individual DB columns 8-), but it's possible and it is very likely to beat any manual method if it has to scale along the size of the project.

BTW, speaking of Sparx EA... I don't know all of its capabilities yet, but it has so many that I would not be surprized if it allowed you to select a class (or even an attribute of a class) and show you other model elements that depend on it in some way. You might want to check this out.

Having said all that, I do understand that you may have at least the following two important concerns about UML:

1. It may appear to require too many modeling details to be in place to get what you want.
2. As any "universal tool", it may be grossly inferior to specialized modeling tools that you already use.

Regarding issue #1: Again, with a good UML tool at hand, you might be able to do as many shortcuts as you want. For example, instead of building a very detailed and accurate activity model for a use case, you could focus just on classes involved in the use case (just enough to enable tracking classes back to use cases). The same applies to UI, of course.

Regarding issue #2: I don't know what exact tools do you use now to model use cases, UI, and DB schema. So, theoretically it is possible that they are all so superior to UML that you wouldn't want to give any of them up in exchange of easier traceability. However, something tells me that your DB modeling tool (with its code-generating capabilities) might be the only one that is truly indispensable. If that's the case, then I would still recommend to consider using UML: you just do not model down to DB schema level and "stop" at the level of domain model (even if you do not have it in your application!). At that point, the UML tool would give you traceability from domain model elements (entities, their attributes, and their relationships) back to use cases and UI elements, and mappings between your domain model and DB schema could be left "in the air" because, in the vast majority of cases, they should be simple enough to track without drawing anything. This might not give you 100% of what you want, but it could give you 80% that would be sufficient to mitigate most of you problems.

The bottom line: if you are using three different tools/technologies to model three different aspects of your system... well, it's obvious that any traceability between those three aspects remains at mercy of those three tools: you could automate only as much as those tools allow (which probably means that you are going to be stuck with a lot of laborous manual tasks to do). As of today, UML appears the only well-defined and widely supported "lingua franca" that could help you to connect your models and could enable automation of substantial part of your analytical activities. Just make sure you distinguish UML "just-drawing tools" (like most of Visio add-ons and stencils) from true UML modeling tools (like Sparx EA and a bunch of others).

Answer (score 0):

Your use cases is a good place to start from.

- Convert your use cases into
  executable test code. This test code
  needs to verify that the resultant
  return values are according to the
  requirements of your use cases.
- The smaller the parts of the work you
  can identify and test, the more
  robust you will be able to build
  your application.
- This means that the interaction of
  your use cases with a large part
  of your database and the GUI, will
  be simpler to understand.

It's hard to lock-down the architecture or business logic interplay in complex projects with complete upfront design of the different layers. One truly learns about what will be able to facilitate your requirements only as you get to the point of implementing them.

As a developer, find the techniques, tools and processes that help you do your job in the best way possible. Don't judge these on their origin. Judge them on their value in making you the best developer possible.

Some items from the agile world has certainly made a big difference to the quality and productivity of my work. This doesn't require throwing out the apple cart and putting an experienced waterfall team into disarray.

Answer (score -1):

The database should model your Problem Domain. It should model it completely enough so that you can extract solutions -- truths -- from it. Bad design is essentially "lying" to the database (allowing the possibility of invalid data or relationships), and when you "lie" to your database, it'll "lie" to you when you ask it questions.

Simple examples are modeling many-to-many relation where a relation can only be one-to-many, or assuming values can't be null, or treating a foreign key as an attribute. Many of these can be avoided by proper normalization, which requires you to explicitly find out what is a key and what isn't.

By "making illegal states unrepresentable" in the model, you avoid having to write "defensive" code to check for the impossible or to validate that a relation is possible, as impossible things are made unrepresentable because of table structures or declarative check constraints.

This lowers the cost of writing your code, as you can concentrate for the most part, on what it needs to do, rather than guarding against the impossible.

Comment: This is great advice for database modeling... but not answering my question.  The need here is to connect features to database elements.  The goal is to know what functionality is affected when changes are made to underlying database elements.